# Issue with AngularJS CheckBox binding, checkbox not checked even if model value is checked

Tags: html, angularjs

I have below code in AngularJS

```
<div >      
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vehicleDetails.selfOwned"> Owned               
</div>  
<div>
{{vehicleDetails.selfOwned}}    
</div>
```

Here selfOwned is my model value which is coming true when printed using

```
{{vehicleDetails.selfOwned}}
```

but still checkbox does not come up with checked, even when model is printing true value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<div>      
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vehicleDetails.selfOwned" ng-checked="vehicleDetails.selfOwned" ng-click="toggleSelection(value)"> Owned               
</div>  
<div>
{{vehicleDetails.selfOwned}}    
</div>
```

In your controller you'll have:

```
$scope.toggleSelection(value){
    vehicleDetails.selfOwned = !vehicleDetails.selfOwned;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it did not worked, ng-checked="true" works but when used with condition, not working. model is coming with correct value. Just that in first time when page loads it does not gets updated according to correct model value.

Comment: Hey buddy, i kepy working on your suggestion and it comes out that the below worked in slight different way- I have to keep it like this.
ng-checked="vehicleDetails.selfOwned=='true'"

Comment: Also i found out that my mistake was that I used the data Type of variable as a String, instead of boolean, so i have to keep it that way.